# Animate a jQuery function

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate, duration

I am having trouble animating a jQuery function so that it doesn't expand instantly but takes a certain amount of time to do so.

My code is as follows:

```
$(function() {
$('.box').click(function(){
    var wWidth = $(window).width();
    var wHeight = $(window).height();
    $(this).width(wWidth);
    $(this).height(wHeight);
    $(this).siblings().addClass('fade')
});
});
```

I have tried using `animate()` and ,slow at the end of my function but I can't get it to work. I also believe I can't use CSS transitions because I am not using classes.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: My first question would be why are you not using CSS classes?  the `.box` is a class, unless I'm sorely mistaken.

Comment: Im not modifying classes constantly. so while it might for the addClass('fade') I dont believe it would work for the width and height changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go:

```
$('.box').click(function(){
    var wWidth = $(window).width();
    var wHeight = $(window).height();
    $(this).animate({width:wWidth+'px',height:wHeight+'px'},1000);
    $(this).siblings().addClass('fade')
});
```

this will take 1000 ms or 1s to expand the `.box` element.

Comment: ah, thank you so much, I didn't know you could do that in jQuery. Thanks for the answer and I am sorry about my lack of knowledge I have just started learning.

Comment: no problem, we've all been beginners (if we are not still), there's nothing to be sorry about! remember that we're all here to learn

Answer (score 1):

you can use `.animate({width:'desired_px'}, desired_time);` and `.animate({height:'desired_px'}, desired_time);` to trigger when you click. try to give your desired_time in milliseconds if predefined words like slow don't work.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".box").hover(function(){                   
            $(this).animate({width:'desired_px'}, desired_time);
            $(this).animate({height:'desired_px'}, desired_time);
        });
 });
```